# What is the name of 90's cartoon about valley of whales?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was broadcast in Israel (and dubbed to Hebrew) in 1995 or 1996 so that makes it probable that it was created between 1993-1996.

The style of drawing suggest french cartoons like "*Journey to the Heart of the World*" (1993)

I remember is that the hero is a kid, possibly an Eskimo or Native American.

There is a bad guy who wants to find the location of this 'Secret Valley of the Whales' or something like that and the kid gets some help from a girl. Possibly there was also an ancient magic spiritual vase that provides directions to that secret place.

Comment: Might be helpful if you could identify what country is 'yours' and what language it was presented in.

Comment: Any idea of the original language? Nothing's coming up in English, and I've searched for a few likely Hebrew words as well, but no images/screenshots show up in the animation style you describe.

Comment: I would think its french in origin, not sure. the mystical "vase" had a significant part in the cartoon i would go far as to say there's eskimo or indian (maybe totem thing) theme to it.   who ever solves this 1 is DA best.

Comment: Found the answer guys! "Legend of the North Wind" (1992) its spanish made

Answer (score 3):

Per Neil's own comment, the cartoon mentioned is [Legend of the North Wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_the_North_Wind_%28film%29), a 1992 Spanish animated fantasy film directed by Juan Bautista Berasategi

[image: Legend of the North Wind]